# What do the coordinates on the Sketchup Ruby API mean?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm very new to the Sketchup API and programming in general so sorry if this is a very basic question. 
I tried clicking on a cuboid I drew and inputted this code to get the coordinates of the bounding box:

```
model = Sketchup.active_model
model_bb = model.bounds
```

However, sketchup returns this:

```
#<Geom::BoundingBox:0x0000005063c360>
```

What does this mean and how can I turn these into x,y,z coordinates that I can work with?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> #<Geom::BoundingBox:0x0000005063c360>
> ```
>
> What does this mean[?]

Its the object being returned by `model.bounds` and being set to `model_bb`. Whilst working with Ruby via the console it will echo back the last returned result.

> how can I turn these into x,y,z coordinates that I can work with?

You can retrieve each of the 8 `Point3d` corners of the Bounding Box with its [`corner(corner_index)`](http://ruby.sketchup.com/Geom/BoundingBox.html#corner-instance_method) method like so

```
points = (0..7).map { |n| model_bb.corner(n) }
```

*You can find out more information by reading the [SketchUp Ruby API Documentation](http://ruby.sketchup.com/)*